# Histogram for list of varying lengths

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a list of lists. The individual lists have varying lengths. I want to plot the histogram for each list. I converted the list of list into a data frame and then tried plotting it.

```
temp_df <- t(rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(list_of_list, t)))
temp_df <- data.frame(temp_df)
ggplot(temp_df, aes(x=temp_df)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
```

I am not able to see any histogram. I am able to plot the histogram if I specify each column in the data frame. But I want to plot all the histogram using a single ggplot. I used melt function to plot the data frame but I get an error with `id.vars` and `measure.vars`. I do not know what to set for both when I want to plot all 6 columns in the data frame.

`temp_df` has 10000 observations for 6 variables. The column names are `X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6`. `X1` has most number of `NA` values and the number of `NA` reduces with each column.

The output for `dput(head(temp_df))`

```
structure(list(X1 = c(0.480449055839274, -0.107119140171712, 
-0.365858052127729, 0.142260729396714, -0.664216637912416, -1.05470170555422
), X2 = c(0.301784141398639, 0.908712942126812, -0.523782030032318, 
-1.11579555551399, 1.37307441850034, 0.280296905306203), X3 = c(-0.874933841230617, 
0.402832753722461, -0.914278256004907, -1.56882801460065, -1.02631196686353, 
-0.187458890178538), X4 = c(3.12470729624475, 0.103689667221851, 
0.635940469415468, 1.28922541408293, 0.372579420923551, -1.0709964435315
), X5 = c(-0.631989132409366, -1.49196931038828, -0.647211733851087, 
-0.367277837168729, -0.988614185107109, 0.38110365216619)), X6 = c(-0.511289132409966, -1.43496932451928, -0.078211457296717, 
-0.251792319052356, -0.893756281930586, 0.19284860482647)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

The values in `list_of_list` are similar to `temp_df`. Each sublist varies in length from 100 to 10000.

Comment: Can you share what your data looks like?  It's an impossible ask given there are no column names...

Comment: @maloneypatr Edited to add `temp_df` data.

Comment: You need to make the data input 100% reproducible. Someone coming to help has no idea what the object called `list_of_list` is like.

Comment: Include the output for `dput(head(temp_df))` in your question...

Comment: @maloneypatr Done

Answer (score 0):

```
temp_df <- structure(
  list(X1 = c(0.480449055839274, -0.107119140171712, -0.365858052127729, 0.142260729396714, -0.664216637912416, -1.05470170555422), 
       X2 = c(0.301784141398639, 0.908712942126812, -0.523782030032318, -1.11579555551399, 1.37307441850034, 0.280296905306203), 
       X3 = c(-0.874933841230617, 0.402832753722461, -0.914278256004907, -1.56882801460065, -1.02631196686353, -0.187458890178538), 
       X4 = c(3.12470729624475, 0.103689667221851,  0.635940469415468, 1.28922541408293, 0.372579420923551, -1.0709964435315), 
       X5 = c(-0.631989132409366, -1.49196931038828, -0.647211733851087,  -0.367277837168729, -0.988614185107109, 0.38110365216619), 
       X6 = c(-0.511289132409966, -1.43496932451928, -0.078211457296717, -0.251792319052356, -0.893756281930586, 0.19284860482647)), 
  row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")

x %>%
  tidyr::gather(var, value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, group = var)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(. ~ var) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]